# loop through results and create views for a new database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012.

I am copying some view from one database to another one. I know I can use Task > Generate scripts to do this for me, however I would like to know how to do this in a different way.

If I run the query select * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS it will obviously return my a list of views in my current database. In the view_definition column I can see it has the scripts to create the views.

Would I would like to know is how to loop through the results from (select * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS) and execute the scripts in the view_definition field? I understand this may not be the best practise however I would just like to learn how you would do such a thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try opening a cursor and creating the view for each row :

```
USE [Target DB];
DECLARE @view VARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE curs CURSOR 
FOR SELECT VIEW_DEFINITION FROM [Source DB].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS

OPEN curs

FETCH NEXT FROM curs 
INTO @view
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 
    EXEC(@view)
    FETCH NEXT FROM curs 
    INTO @view
END 
CLOSE curs
DEALLOCATE curs
```